# A (mild?) question on the number of monomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials

Let $[n]_q=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$ with $[0]_q=0$. Recall the $q$-factorials $[n]_q!=[1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q$ (with $[0]_q!=1$) and the $q$-binomials
$$\binom{n}k_q=\frac{[n]_q!}{[k]_q!\,[n-k]_q!}.$$

Now, consider the polynomials
$$W_n(q):=\frac{1-q^{3n}}{1-q^{2n}}\binom{2n}n_q.$$
**Examples.** $W_1(q)=q^2+q+1$ and $W_2(q)=q^6 + q^5 + 2q^4 + q^3 + 2q^2 + q + 1$.

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? The number of monomials in $W_n(q)$ equals $n^2+n+1$.

Comment: Is it obvious the $W_n(q)$ are indeed polynomials in $q$?

Comment: Don't you just compute $\deg W_n$?

Comment: @SamHopkins: it's not obvious. But, similar techniques proving Gaussian polynomials and $q$-Catalan polynomials should do it.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: it's related, but one needs to show there are no internal zeroes (missing terms).

Comment: Is it true that all coefficients of $W_n$ are non-negative?

Comment: @PietroMajer: from what I see, yes, the coefficients seem positive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the fact that $1-q^{3n}=(1-q^{2n})+q^{2n}(1-q^n)$, we can write
$$W_n(q)=\binom{2n}{n}_q+q^{2n}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}_q$$
and then the result follows from the fact that the degree of $W_n(q)$ is $n^2+n$, together with the fact that $q$-binomial coefficients are polynomials in $q$ with positive coefficients (unimodal even).